# SDL_GL_SetAttribute causes some opengl functions to be null

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

Setting values higher, for example 32 for `SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE` causes `glCreateShader` to be null.

I don't know what is causing this behavior, because I don't get any errors while setting attributes and creating context. Here's a minimalistic example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_opengl.h>

const int WIDTH = 800;
const int HEIGHT = 600;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    int response;
    response = SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, 
        SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);

    response = SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    response = SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3);
    response = SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);

    if (response < 0) {
        std::cout << "Setting Attribute: DEPTH_SIZE Failed\n";
        return 0;
    }

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("TestApp", WIDTH >> 1, HEIGHT >> 1, WIDTH, HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    if (window == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "window not setup\n";
        return 0;
    }

    SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    if (context == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "context failed\n";
        return 0;
    }

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    if (GLEW_OK != glewInit()) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize glew\n";
        return 0;
    }

    glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    int value; 
    SDL_GL_GetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, &value);
    std::cout << "Querying Depth size: " << value << "\n";

    std::cout << "glEnable: " << (glEnable ? "Available" : "NULL") << "\n";
    std::cout << "glCreateShader: " << (glCreateShader ? "Available" : "NULL") << "\n";

    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(context);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

output for `DEPTH_SIZE = 24 bits`

```
Querying Depth size: 24
glEnable: Available
glCreateShader: Available
```

output for `DEPTH_SIZE = 32 bits`

```
Querying Depth size: 32
glEnable: Available
glCreateShader: NULL
```

Comment: What if you use the compatibility profile instead of the core? GLEW is known (or at least was used to be known) for not working well with core profile, at least on windows.

Comment: Check your `GL_VERSION`/`GL_VENDOR`/`GL_RENDERER` strings in each case too, if you are on Windows you might be getting the Microsoft GDI software fallback (which only exposes OpenGL 1.1 or 1.4, hence the missing `glCreateShader()`) on the 32-bit depth buffer case.

Comment: @genpfault you are right. Its fall backing to 1.1.0

Comment: Use `SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(...)` before `glewInit()`.